# How to fix and prevent VirtualBox Kernel driver not installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, kernel

Today I noticed that my VirtualBox VMs no longer start. With messages

```
The virtual machine 'CGI' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:
MachineWrap
Interface:
IMachine
Unknown macro: {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

And

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

It seems this is caused by a kernel update. I actually wasn't aware that Ubuntu is doing automatic kernel updates. The log `/var/log/dpkg.log` shows that kernel update was going on right before problems started.

`sudo dpkg --list | grep linux-image` shows images lines with many 4.8, 4.10 and 4.13 versions.

```
[user:~] $ uname -a
Linux io 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The suggested solution for this problem unfortunately does not work.

```
[root:~] # /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-27-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-41-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-45-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-49-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-52-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-54-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-56-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
[root:~] #
```

The install log `/var/log/vbox-install.log` is too large to post here but it starts with following message

```
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;
```

There are actually three questions now I think
* How do I fix kernel configuration?
* How do I fix VirtualBox? Should I remove and reinstall?
* How do I prevent these types of issues? Should I disable auto-updates of kernel?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not installed currently. Is that the problem? Why kernel upgrades are not working?

Comment: I ran into the same problem with Arch Linux after some updates. 
sudo /sbin/vboxreload did the job for me. Found that solution by coincidence after neither /sbin/vboxconfig existed nor reinstalling would work on my machine.

Comment: I posted the solution of this issue [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1438279/how-to-sign-a-kernel-module-ubuntu-18-04/1513506#1513506)

Answer (score 33):

I met the same issue after VirtualBox upgrade to 5.2.6 r120293

Linux kernel version 4.14.13-041413-generic

The following commands sequence helped for me:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms && sudo apt install libelf-dev
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Comment: This also worked today with a persistent inability to reinstall Virtualbox 6.0 on 4.15.0-58-generic.

Comment: Did not work for me on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Did not work for Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Didn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 (Jan 20, 2020). Was running v 6.0, completely uninstalled 6.0 and then installed 6.1 and now it's working. Good luck all!

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The first commend works in my ubuntu 20.04, did not use the second. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works with 22.x

Comment: Works on 22.04.3 although it appears to downgrade virtualbox from 7.0.14 to 6.1.48

Answer (score 10):

> `$ sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms && sudo apt install libelf-dev`

just this solved the same problem on my Kubuntu 18.4.2

Comment: You're providing same answer as provided before. Look first answer. You can write comment it if you want to say something about it or you can upvote previous answer. https://superuser.com/a/1286104/774524

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as the one before?

Comment: by this I was going to say it worked for me WITHOUT 
< $ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig >

Answer (score 6):

After reinstalling `virtualbox-dkms` as above, you may also have to `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` to reload the kernel module.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, re-installing Virtualbox fixes the issue

Comment: It is March 2023, and I can confirm that this has worked for me on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubuntu or Debian distribution (or either derivative of either), the driver management should be automatically handled by `dkms` if you have it installed.

If you didn't previously have `dkms` you can fix the problem for the currently running kernel version and Virtualbox version by executing the `vboxconfig` as `root`. In practice you can open new terminal window (with `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`T` by default) and simply type `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` and press enter.

If you don't have `dkms` installed, you'll experience similar problem in the future, too, when Virtualbox or Linux kernel is updated next time. To avoid that, you can run `sudo apt install dkms`, too.