# Host: [Ubuntu 21.04] Guest: [Window 10] -- Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-21.10

When I started the Windows10 from Virtualbox. it's not working. here is more information from the pop-up error box

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows10.

The virtual machine 'Windows10' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: MachineWrap Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

for someone who is more Linux-savvy, and familiar with Virtualbox, this could be a simple issue, but I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

as troubleshooting steps:

```
I even downloaded and installed the latest VM box
I rebooted the Ubuntu Host system a few times, hoping for some miracle to happen.
```

if someone could give me direction on how to get this Windows10 up and running, that's be very sweet.

Thank you very much

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051161/virtualbox-ns-error-failure-0x80004005

Comment: Many causes and solutions: See [link1](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8687), [link2](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=92494), [link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995338/vboxmanage-is-unable-to-start-vm-code-ns-error-failure-ubuntu-16-04), [link4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051161/virtualbox-ns-error-failure-0x80004005), [link5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007488/i-get-an-error-when-creating-a-vm-on-virtualbox).

Comment: See if this helps you: .....    https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=87306#:~:text=%5Bmod%20note%5D%20NS_ERROR_FAILURE%20%280x80004005%29%20is%20a%20general%20failure,supplemental%20error%20description%20then%20we%20can%27t%20help%20you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix and prevent VirtualBox Kernel driver not installed](https://superuser.com/questions/1285964/how-to-fix-and-prevent-virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind help!! unfortunately none of the answers above worked for me. I have provided the system info above, if you happen to know a concrete troubleshooting steps to help me UNINSTALL like VirtualBox was never installed before, I am gonna try to reinstall as "brand new". Thank you!

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I went back to read line by line, tried all the commands, I guess the first time it didn't click, after two struggles two more days, it finally occur to me to try one of the commands and fix that output of that command helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @ChanganAuto provided, I tried this command, and noticed the last line, '/usr' was world-open, that's why it's unusable.

> $ VBoxManage list extpacks Extension Packs: 1 Pack no. 0:   Oracle VM
> VirtualBox Extension Pack Version:      5.2.14 Revision:     123301
> Edition:       Description:  USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 Host Controller, Host
> Webcam, VirtualBox RDP, PXE ROM, Disk Encryption, NVMe. VRDE Module:
> VBoxVRDP Usable:       true

=====
I changed the access level to that folder;

sudo chmod 755 /usr

then it started working.

*** my lesson from this, next time run , based on the output, fix that issue may suffice to take care of the unable to start the Virtualbox issue.

Thank you everyone who provided valuable feedback on this question!